# creating a folder once user registred laravel 5 Laravel 5.2

Tags: filesystems, laravel-5, registration

I would like to create a folder inside Storage folder in Laravel 5.2, once you register and pick your username, a folder with that username will be created for you. For Example : if you create username : 'laraveluser' an folder will be create inside public folder named 'laraveluser'. But I can not understand how can do it. here my problems and code of UserController:

but it showing :

```
FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 28: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\File' not found

    in UserController.php line 28

    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Model\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;



class UserController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
     public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        File::MakeDirectory(public_path($data['username']));
        return User::create([
            'fullname' => $data['fullname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
            'company_name' => $data['company_name'],
            'website' => $data['website'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'status' => $data['status'],
        ]);

        //File::makeDirectory(public_path($data['username']));
       // return $user;

    }
     protected $redirectPath = '/manage-user';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write this:

```
use File;
```

It'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;` after the namespace. Your file facade was not loaded.